# DEPRECATION: gpg 1.14.0-unknown has a non-standard version number

Tags: python, pip, gnupg

I do have installed pip-23.3.1 on Debian/Raspberian Bullseye,
I am not aware how that gpg 1.14.0-unknown got installed, details are

pip show gpg
Name: gpg
Version: 1.14.0-unknown
Summary: Python bindings to the GPGME API of the GnuPG cryptography library.
Home-page: https://www.gnupg.org
Author: The GnuPG hackers
Author-email: gnupg-devel@gnupg.org
License: LGPL2.1+ (the library), GPL2+ (tests and examples)
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

pip show a deprecation warning for the next 24.0 release, so I need to upgrade at least that "naming" of "gpg 1.14.0-unknown"
DEPRECATION: gpg 1.14.0-unknown has a non-standard version number. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of gpg or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming version number. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063

One hint was:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=355615
"It is an upstream Debian issue. They need to fix it with a new python3-gpg package."

Any help welcome.

Tried to update the gpg pip package, expecting to solve / update the package but without luck